# How to parsing date column to month & day only?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'am very confused to get someone's birthday date by changing Y-m-d to m-d in the date_birth field. How should I do? This is my current code:

```
$getBirthday = Karyawan::where('date_birth', Carbon::now()->format('m-d'))->get();
```

Thanks, I want to get someone's birthday by taking m-d only from date_birth field. Hope u're helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query using the mysql DATE_FORMAT method and using `whereRaw`

```
$getBirthday = Karyawan::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m-%d') = ?", [Carbon::now()->format('m-d')])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get in the day and month same, you can also use this:

```
$getBirthday = Karyawan::whereDay('date_birth', Carbon::now()->format('d'))
                   ->whereMonth('date_birth', Carbon::now()->format('m'))->get();
```

See also: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses